# How to exclude deleted fields from Apex Tooling API query

Tags: tooling-api

I have an object with a couple of deleted (and erased) fields. When I try and run a query like this using the Apex Tooling API

```
(List<ToolingAPI.CustomField>)toolingAPI.query('Select Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, TableEnumOrId, MetaData From CustomField Where TableEnumOrId = \'' + customObjectId + '\'').records;
```

I get this result :

> [ {   "message" : "invalid cross reference id",   "errorCode" :
>   "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY" } ]

The problem seems to be with the MetaData. Excluding that from the query succeeds.

The two deleted fields remain in the (successful) response when the MetaData is excluded with a suffix of `_del_del`.

Both fields were 'erased' and remain invisible in the object configuration.

Is there any way to hard remove these deleted fields?

Is there any way to at least exclude deleted fields from the Apex Tooling API query ?

Comment: can you please share what does the successful response look like?